# How to finish jagged edge of kitchen subway tile?

Tags: kitchens, tile, diy-vs-pro

Did our own backsplash tiling in the kitchen, and didn't realize until we were finished that the cap/trim/edging goes UNDER the tile. Not on top.

So now we've got an ugly looking edge to the tile (our cuts weren't very clean — we assumed we would cover them after). Pics attached. 
Ideas for how we can hide this?

DIY hacks and/or product names/ideas are welcome!

[image: ugly edge of tile]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar situation. I purchased some outside corner moulding, similar to this:

[image]

and used that on the edge. I had to run it down the table saw to rip it to the correct depth. I used an all purpose adhesive to attach it, and then finished the edges with caulk.

Comment: Looks like a good idea to me. Then paint it with a high-gloss paint tinted to be a close match to the tile.

Comment: @SPS, just take a level and make sure the trim is plumb. It looks like your tile edge goes further out towards the top, you may have to shave it down before adding the trim.

Answer (score 9):

If you go to a large tile store you should be able to find an edge similar to this in ceramic. [image: Tile edge]

Answer (score 7):

The only way to do it right is to pop those ten tiles and just redo it. I say this based on 19 years' experience. You won't regret it in the end. The thing about going over the tile with a wood or ceramic molding is that there is no give, and the tiles are not sitting even. The molding will sit on the highest tile and you will have gaps (blacklining) in the lower one.

Yes, you can caulk it but then you are creating a lip, and I promise you something will catch/hook/snag someday; you'll regret it's there.

I recommend you pop the tiles, clean it up, and ready them to install. Get out your tape and level and set the schluter first. Use adhesive (mastic I assume), double-sided tape, or -- in a pinch -- nails with very flat heads to secure the schluter. Cut the tile into the schluter.

Dry set the tile first. just to make sure they are cut properly, then back butter the tile -- avoiding a mess if you have to re-cut. If you are a little tight just use a file, sanding paper, or even a concrete step to take off a 16th. Alternatively, you can chalk a line or use a straight edge to mark where the tile should end. Don't worry about the schluter until you are done with the tiles. Just concentrate on hitting the line. When you are setting the tile, make sure there is a little extra glue on the edge of the tile where your end point (line) is. Now when your tile is finished slip the schluter underneath the tile. Press firmly on the tile (grout floats are great way to apply even pressure), wiping away access adhesive until the tile are flush with the schluter.

Or a quick method. Now I've done this and have found its better to take the extra time, unless you have a real steady hand. You can mark a straight line and use an angle grinder to cut a straight line and install a border tile. That way it is at least flush with the rest. **If you mist the tile and the angle grinder wheel you will cut down on friction and dust.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is great information, but it's hard to understand along with all the extraneous comments.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an angle grinder to clean up the edge a bit, then nail wood 1/4 round trim along there. Use paintable caulk to hide the seam, then paint with high gloss to match (or complement/contrast) the tile.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bite the bullet and pop off that last column of tiles.  It looks like its only 11 tiles.  It'll take just a few hours and you'll be so much happier if you re-do it right.

Any kind of band-aid will always look like a band-aid and you will never be happy with it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a little shy on cash and want to do a cheap fix try this. I did it and it got me by. Put a straight edge on the tile just level with the shortest tile top to bottom and make sure its straight. Put tape top to bottom along that line. Now stand back and look at it to make sure the tiles are level. Sometimes the entire wall has tiles which are headed up or down. If it's straight enough then get a grinder and make a cut along that tape. Then get a chisel and take your time and pout it from edge inward and get them off. You're going to gouge the wall a bit. Don't worry about it just do the best you can. Sand it afterwards. Leave that tape on if any 9f the  wall needs to be touched up or painted nows the time. Wait till it's dry and mask where u want the grout to end. Get a small container of grout do the edge between the tape. It's a.cheap way and any tile pro will know you should have used proper trim or whatever but anyone else won't even give it a second look. It'll be fine. As an adoption you can sand the wall then grout then tape the grout then paint the wall but it's far better the other way. If the tape pulls off some fresh paint u can touch it up.later. better tape is worth it for this. Or paper from top to bottom and just tape ends.

Answer (score 0):

Made the same mistake on my shower.

I put a narrow furring strip the thickness of the tile, and about 3/4" wide. Attached that to the wall.

This gave me an ugly variable width gap between the strip and the tile ends.  I mixed up a small batch of grout and filled this.  Don't worry about colour matching.  It will be covered.

Picked up a 1.25" wide seam sealer strip at Home Depot.  These are used for junctions between different kinds of lino or vinyl.  Put a generous bead of caulk on top of the ground, and fastened the sealer strip to the furring strip.